# Power Automate Filter List items by person login name

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, user-profile, modern-experience, flow, power-automate

We need to filter the list items by person login name (fully qualified i.e, `i:0#.f|membership|xyz@abc.com`),

How we can achieve this using Power automate GetList Items method or through REST API,

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Get User Id from SharePoint using user login name:

REST API endpoint: `/_api/web/siteusers('<login-name>')?$select=Id`

[image]

Flow expression used: `uriComponent(variables('loginName'))`

Complete Uri: `_api/web/siteusers('@{uriComponent(variables('loginName'))}')?$select=Id`

2. Filter SharePoint list items using user ID:

[image]

**References**:

1. [SharePoint REST API: Get User Id by User Name](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/798407/SharePoint-REST-API-Get-User-Id-by-User-Name)
2. [get items - filter person field](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/get-items-filter-person-field/td-p/291139)
3. [Microsoft Docs - uricomponent() function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#uricomponent)
4. [Parsing JSON in Microsoft Flow](https://prairiedeveloper.com/2018/12/parsing-json-in-microsoft-flow/)

Comment: Hi @Pradeep, Does this answers your question? If Yes, Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it will help others with same problem in future. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list. If you have any doubt please ask here.